# protobuf data parsing return incorrect result

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

We have a data pipeline to fetch data from mosquitto broker using **python paho client**. We managed to fetch the protobuf data as below:

```
1.0.0/LOC/SPOT_GOB/xxxx-xxxx/GPB_LOCR 0 b'\n+\n\txxxx-xxxx\x12\x0c6CC7ECA59000\x1d\xb8~\xe0c%\x008\x98C(\x020\xb0\xe5\xac\xe8x05'
```

....

The protobuf are coming in continuously. The issue happens when we use the python script to parse the data.

My protobuf file content:

```
syntax = "proto2";
Package location;


message Locations {
    extensions 1001 to max;


  // An outlier is defined when x = y = 0
  message Location {
    optional string venue_id          = 1; // ID of the Venue
    optional string mac               = 2; // Detected/Located device MAC address
    optional float  x                 = 3; // x-coordinates of the detected device (possible to be 0)
    optional float  y                 = 4; // y-coordinates of the detected device (possible to be 0)
    optional uint32 floor_number      = 5; // positive integer of the floor number where the device is detected
    optional uint32 timestamp         = 6; // Unix timestamp when the device is detected (even when it is an outlier)
  }
  repeated Location locations = 1;
}
```

my location_pb2.py file content:

```
import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='location.proto',
  package='wifi_location',
  syntax='proto2',
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x0elocation.proto\x12\rwifi_location\"\xb6\x01\n\tLocations\x12\x34\n\tlocations\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32!.wifi_location.Locations.Location\x1ah\n\x08Location\x12\x10\n\x08venue_id\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0b\n\x03mac\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\t\n\x01x\x18\x03 \x01(\x02\x12\t\n\x01y\x18\x04 \x01(\x02\x12\x14\n\x0c\x66loor_number\x18\x05 \x01(\r\x12\x11\n\ttimestamp\x18\x06 \x01(\r*\t\x08\xe9\x07\x10\x80\x80\x80\x80\x02')
)




_LOCATIONS_LOCATION = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Location',
  full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='venue_id', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.venue_id', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='mac', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.mac', index=1,
      number=2, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='x', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.x', index=2,
      number=3, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='y', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.y', index=3,
      number=4, type=2, cpp_type=6, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=float(0),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='floor_number', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.floor_number', index=4,
      number=5, type=13, cpp_type=3, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='timestamp', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.Location.timestamp', index=5,
      number=6, type=13, cpp_type=3, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=101,
  serialized_end=205,
)

_LOCATIONS = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Locations',
  full_name='wifi_location.Locations',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='locations', full_name='wifi_location.Locations.locations', index=0,
      number=1, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[_LOCATIONS_LOCATION, ],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=True,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[(1001, 536870912), ],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=34,
  serialized_end=216,
)

_LOCATIONS_LOCATION.containing_type = _LOCATIONS
_LOCATIONS.fields_by_name['locations'].message_type = _LOCATIONS_LOCATION
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Locations'] = _LOCATIONS
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

Locations = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Locations', (_message.Message,), dict(

  Location = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Location', (_message.Message,), dict(
    DESCRIPTOR = _LOCATIONS_LOCATION,
    __module__ = 'location_pb2'
    # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:wifi_location.Locations.Location)
    ))
  ,
  DESCRIPTOR = _LOCATIONS,
  __module__ = 'location_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:wifi_location.Locations)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Locations)
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Locations.Location)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope
```

My python script:

```
From location_pb2 import Locations

Def on_message(mqtt, obj, msg):

W = Locations()
    RW = W.SerializeToString()
    Print(RW)
    A = W.ParseFromString(RW)
    Print (A)
```

the end result of the parsing as below:

```
b ''
0
b ''
0
b ''
....
```

the properly parsed data should come out as *venue_id, mac, x, y, floor number, timestamp*.

Comment: How are you finding the message boundaries in the pipeline? How do you know where one message ends and the next begins? See [this note](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming) on streaming.

Comment: Hi David, thank for reply. I have added in my location_pb2.py file with the message descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the documentation at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial?

I'd recommend you jump to the section "Compiling Your Protocol Buffers". Take the https://github.com/rksg/gpb_mqtt_sample_client/blob/master/protobuf_bindings/src/main/proto/spot_locations.proto file and run

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/spot_locations.proto
```

Comment: The output you get is the class structure to correctly work with the incoming protocol buffer payload received over the MQTT bridge.

Comment: hi yeong sheng, thanks for the reply. I compile the protocol buffers directly from the spot_locations.proto file using the same command.

Comment: I hope the questions took you down the right direction to reach your solution.

Comment: Glad it helped if it did.